# how is the expression invalid in my simple query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm new to SQL, creating a simple query from an identical example but not sure why 1 expression is invalid?

I tried this statement:

```
SELECT      
    A.AccountId,
    A.Address1_City,
    A.Address1_Country,
    A.Address1_PostalCode,
    A.Address1_StateOrProvince,
    A.CreatedOn,
    A.EMailAddress1,
    A.mcs_ABN2,
    A.mcs_AdminContact,
    A.mcs_AdminContactName,
    A.mcs_AreyouinterestedinInternationalDevelopmen,
    A.mcs_BenefitsUtilised,
    A.mcs_BusinessNameOrganisationName,
    A.mcs_doyouprovideaccreditedtraining,
    A.mcs_doyouprovidenonaccreditedtraining,
    A.mcs_DoyouprovideservicesinanyNDISTrialSites,
    A.mcs_DoyouprovideservicestoChildrenYoungPeople,
    A.mcs_DummyRecord,
    A.mcs_EntityStatusCode,
    A.mcs_IndustryOperatingIn,
    A.mcs_IsStreetAddresssameasPostalAddress,
    A.mcs_MembershipNote,
    A.mcs_MultiStateDepartment,
    A.mcs_NotefromApplicant,
    A.mcs_NumberofEmployeesDec,
    A.mcs_OtherTradingNameOrganisationName,
    A.mcs_PartnerDisabilityServiceOrganisations,
    A.mcs_PrimaryProductsServicesToPromote,
    A.mcs_RevenueDisabServiceProvisionTotalAnnual,
    A.mcs_SageERPCustomerCode,
    A.mcs_SageErpExportFlag,
    A.ModifiedOn,
    A.Name,
    A.nds_Account_MembershipNumberCopy,
    A.nds_IsMember,
    A.nds_MainContact,
    A.nds_MainContactName,
    A.nds_MemberCategoryCopy,
    A.PrimaryContactId,
    A.Revenue,
    A.Revenue_Base,
    A.StatusCode,
    A.WebSiteURL
FROM
    account A
WHERE
    A.statuscode = 1
GROUP BY
    A.name
```

and got this error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column 'account.AccountId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Do you mean to use ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY?

Comment: sorry Gordon, i expect it looks clear... like i said i copied this from a near identical example that parsed ok.. what if i don't want to group by or count/ave/sum records with that expression?

Comment: p.s. very first use of stackoverflow... thanks for the quick help guys

Answer (score 3):

`Group By` is for aggregate functions (`Count, Sum, etc`), so if you use group by you need to group by at least every column being returned in the select SQL, otherwise it wouldn't be able to do the aggregation. This looks like you just want to order by Name though, so if you replace

```
GROUP BY          A.name
```

with

```
ORDER BY A.name
```

it should work. If you don't care about order or aggregation just remove that part of the query entirely.